# A Security Package Specific Error Occurred

Tags: vb.net, plc, opc

I have created a VB.NET winform application using `QuickOPC Classic 5.12` to subscribe data from `OPC Server(remote machine)`. It has been working without any problems for last 10 months. But now I get the error `'A Security Package Specific Error Occurred'`.

I have tested the connection with the OPC server using

```
1) MatrikonOPC Explorer
2) Software Toolbox OPCData.NET Browse Demo (using OPC Web Client 3.02)
```

I have able to connect the OPC server and subscripe the tag values withot any error.

The error occurs only in `QuickOPC Classic 5.12` application.

My questions:

```
1) What is the reason for this error and how to fix it?
2) If the problem persist on the DCOM setup, then what are the settings 
   to be rechecked to fix this error?
```

Comment: Disclaimer: I represent the QuickOPC product vendor. You can ask on QuickOPC online forums, http://www.opclabs.com/forum/index . Note that the version you are using is old and no longer officially supported. Are you completely unable to get the data (does the error always appear), or is a transient problem?

Comment: @ZbynekZ: Thanks. I have also posted in QuickOPC online forums.

Comment: @ZbynekZ: For past 2 days, the error always appear. The application get the data from 4 remote OPC servers. The other 3 are working without any erros. The error come from the particular machine.

Comment: @ZbynekZ: The link for the  QuickOPC online forums is http://www.opclabs.com/forum/reading-writing-subscriptions-property-access/1566-a-security-package-specific-error-occurred